# An Interesting Resource Allocation Problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Here is the problem:
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize} & \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{1 + \textrm{exp}(C_i + x_i)}\\
\text{subject to} & \sum_{i=1}^N x_i \le R \\
& x_i \ge 0, ~ i = 1,2,...,N
\end{array}

$C_1,C_2,...,C_N$ are real numbers and can be positives, zeros and negatives.The problem seems to be easy, but after several days I still have no idea on solving it. Thanks for any comments.

Comment: Hint:  In order for the various partial derivatives of your objective function to be equal, you need all the $C_i+x_i$ to be equal.  From here it's simple algebra.

Comment: @WillO, are you sure that takes into account the simplex constraint?

Comment: This problem is not convex unless $\min_i C_i\geq 0$; and since you've explicitly said that $C_i$ can be negative, it cannot be treated as convex. I've removed the convex optimization tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this problem interesting to consider! What application does it come from? It is not convex unless $\min_i C_i\geq 0$; and since you've explicitly said that $C_i$ can be negative, it cannot be treated as convex. Furthermore, the problem is infeasible if $R<0$ and trivial if $R=0$, so let us assume that $R>0$.

Because the constraints are linear and the objective is smooth, the KKT conditions are necessary conditions that any optimum must satsify. These conditions are built around the Lagrangian
\begin{aligned}
L(x,\lambda,\nu) &= \sum_i \frac{1}{1+\exp(C_i+x_i)} - \sum_i \lambda_i x_i - \nu ( R - \sum_i x_i ) \\ &= -R\nu + \sum_i \frac{1}{1+\exp(C_i+x_i)} + (\nu-\lambda_i) x_i
\end{aligned}
where $\lambda_i\geq 0$, $i=1,2,\dots,n$ are the Lagrange multipliers for $x_i\geq 0$, and $\nu \geq 0$ is the Lagrange multiplier for $\sum_i x_i \leq R$. The conditions are:

- Stationarity: $$\frac{\exp(C_i+x_i)}{(1+\exp(C_i+x_i))^2}=\nu-\lambda_i, \quad i=1,2,\dots, n.$$
- Primal and dual feasibility: 
  $$\sum_i x_i \leq R \quad \nu\geq 0 \quad x_i,\lambda_i\geq 0, ~ i=1,2,\dots, n$$
- Complementary slackness:
  $$\nu \left( R- \sum_i x_i \right) = 0 \quad\Longrightarrow\quad \nu =0 ~~\text{or}~~\sum_i x_i=R$$
  $$\lambda_i x_i = 0 \quad\Longrightarrow\quad x_i=0~~\text{or}~~\lambda_i=0, \quad i=1,2,\dots, n.$$

The complementary slackness condition on $\nu$ is not that helpful, because it *must* be true that $\sum_i x_i = R$ at the optimum. After all, if $\sum_i x_i < R$, then we can increase any $x_i$ until equality is achieved, and decrease the objective when doing so.

The complementary slackness condition on $\lambda$ is much more interesting.
Note the implication: if $x_i>0$, then $\lambda_i=0$, which means
$$x_i > 0 \quad\Longrightarrow\quad \frac{\exp(C_i+x_i)}{(1+\exp(C_i+x_i))^2}=\nu$$
In other words, all of the nonzero values of $x_i$ must obtain the same value for that left-hand quantity. Solving for $\exp(C_i+x_i)$ we have
$$\exp(C_i+x_i) = -1 + \frac{1}{2\nu} ( 1 \pm \sqrt{1-2\nu} )$$
We already have $\nu\geq 0$, and in order for the right-hand side to be real, we must also have $\nu\leq 1/2$. Inspection tells us that for $\nu\in(0,1/2)$, only one of the roots is positive; and when $\nu=1/2$, both are zero. Therefore, we *do* have
$$x_i > 0 \quad\Longrightarrow\quad x_i = \log\left(-1 + \frac{1}{2\nu}( 1 + \sqrt{1-2\nu} )\right)-C_i \quad\nu\in(0,1/2)$$
The messy right-hand quantity is irrelevant: we now know that *all nonzero values of $x_i$ must obtain the same value of $C_i+x_i$.*

This leads us to what is called a [water-filling algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_filling_algorithm). The idea is this: we start with the smallest value of $C_i$, and start "adding water" $C_i+x_i$ until it equals the  *next* smallest value, say $C_j$. We then add to both $C_i+x_i=C_j+x_j$ until they equal the third smallest value. The process continues until we reach $\sum_i x_i = R$.

EDIT: It is clear that that one part of this where I *do* handwave, describing the water filling algorithm, is not correct. But note that Bob's example below *does satisfy the optimality conditions above*. I'll be thinking about this and edit further as necessary.

Comment: Here is the background. The total resource is R and needs to be allocated to N users. $\frac{1}{1 + exp(C_i + x_i)}$ is the unsatisfaction score of user $i$ if he/she receives recourse $x_i$. We want to minimize the total unsatisfactoin score of N users.

Comment: That does indeed suggest water filling: satisfy the most unsatisfied person first, until there is a tie, etc.

Comment: I guess the water-filling part is incorrect. For example, when we have 3 users, $C_1 = -7$, $C_2 = -6$, $C_3 = 1$ and $R = 10$. The optimal solution is $x_1^* = 0$, $x_2^* = 8.5$ and $x_3^* = 1.5$. This result is based on global search. But the water filling result is different.

Comment: It is like if some user is in a very bad situation, we have to give up the user.

Comment: Hmm. I am sure you're right. I might have gotten the derivative wrong which would suggest a different water filling. Let me look further

Comment: Actually your result looks like a reverse water fill---note that users 2 and 3 end up with the same score. It is consistent with the optimality conditions I laid out! The only part that failed is my hand waving! I will fix. Perhaps my solution *maximizes* dissatisfaction ;-)

Comment: Let me give another example: 3 users, $C_1=−4, C_2=−2, C_3=3$ and R=10. The optimal solution is $x_1^*=6, x_2^*=4$ and $x_3^*=0$, which is not a reverse water filling. The KKT conditions give the necessary conditions for optimal solution. However, to find the optimal one is difficult.

Comment: Very interesting! I suspect non-convexity is confounding us.

Comment: I agree. The problem looks to be so simple but many of my efforts solving it go to failure in the end.

Comment: I'm glad I removed the convex-optimization tag :-)

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried to analyse the problem from the derivative viewpoint. Allocate a small amount of resource to the user who has the most negative derivative. However, as more resource is allocated to a user, the derivative can go down first and go up later. This greedy algorithm sometimes cannot find the optimal solution.

Comment: Perhaps you can try a sweep: start with the smallest $C_i$ and fill from there. Then start with the second-smallest. Then start with the third smallest... And so on. Do you have any evidence that the group of nonzero $x$ values is non-contiguous?

Comment: This is a good point. Right now, I think the sweep works. The sweep takes O(n^2) times and the overall complexity is O(n^3). That is really a good news. Thank you so much.

Comment: This is a simplified problem. The original problem can be \begin{eqnarray} &\arg\min_{x_1,x_2,...,x_N}\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{1 + \textrm{exp}(C_i + w_i x_i)};\\
& \sum_{i=1}^N x_i \le R; \\
& x_i \ge 0, \,\,\, \textrm{for}  \,\,\, i = 1,2,...,N. \end{eqnarray} where $w_i$s are positive real numbers.  Another extension is \begin{eqnarray}
&\min \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \frac{1}{1 + \textrm{exp}\left(C_i + w_1 x_{i,1} + w_2 x_{i,2}\right)} ; \\
&\sum_{i = 1}^{N} x_{i,1} \le R_1; \\
&\sum_{i = 1}^{N} x_{i,2} \le R_2; \\
&x_{i,1} \ge 0; \\
&x_{i,2} \ge 0.
\end{eqnarray} where we have two resources.

Comment: In these two tricky problems, do yo have any suggestions and comments? It seems the sweep doesn't work here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think the second problem is equivalent to \begin{eqnarray}
&\min \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \frac{1}{1 + \textrm{exp}\left(C_i +x_{i}\right)} ; \\
&\sum_{i = 1}^{N} x_{i} \le w_1 R_1 + w_2 R_2; \\
&x_{i} \ge 0.
\end{eqnarray}.

Comment: The key here is that the optimality conditions reduce the degrees of freedom to one. That remains true even for the single resource weighted case, so I will bet some sort of sweep is still possible. For the two resource case, I suspect you have two degrees of freedom, and I am not sure what the full consequences are.