# How to solve this convex resource allocation problem numerically? CVX doesn't work.

Tags: numerical-methods, convex-optimization

I got a resource allocation problem as follows: 
\begin{eqnarray}
\min &\sum_{i=1}^M \frac{1}{1 + \text{exp}(C_i + \frac{r_i}{1+r_i})} ;\\
&\sum_{i=1}^M r_i \le R;\\
&r_i  \ge 0 \,\,\,\text{for}\,\,\, i = 1,2,...,M.
\end{eqnarray}
The objective function is convex and the constraints are linear. For simplicity, assume $C_i = 1$ for $i = 1,2,...,M$. When I tried to use CVX to solve the problem, I rewrite the problem as follows:

cvx_begin

```
variable x(M) nonnegative
minimize( sum(inv_pos(1 + exp(x))) )
subject to
    sum(inv_pos(2-x)) <= R + M
    x >= 1
    x < 2
```

cvx_end

where $x_i = 1 + \frac{r_i}{1+r_i}$. However, CVX cannot solve it, since 1/(1 +exp(x)), x>0 is not thought to be convex.

Is there any other way to rewrite the problem, such that CVX can solve it? Or is there any other good tool to use? Thx :)

Comment: It is not that it "thinks" your function is not convex. After all, it doesn't think. Rather, CVX requires *you* to prove convexity, and to do so by following its limited set of rules. Each rule corresponds to a step in its transformation process; your proof is a recipe, of sorts. So if you cannot express your model according to its rules, you effectively cannot tell CVX how to solve it!

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to prove  1/(1 +exp(x)), x>0 is convex to CVX?

Comment: No, there is not. A proof cannot be constructed from set of rules/transformations CVX implements.

Comment: It seems reasonable to cite your other question, given these models are so similar: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1096457/52878

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have checked that the cost $f$ is convex. Note that if $\Pi$ is a permutation matrix, then $f(x) = f(\Pi x)$ and if $x$ satisfies the constraints then so does $\Pi x$.

Let $\Pi$ be the permutation that just shifts 'left', that is,
$\Pi (x_1,...,x_n)^T = (x_2,x_3,...,x_n,x_1)^T$. Then we see that
$f({1 \over n}(x+\Pi x+\cdots+ \Pi^{n-1} x)) \le f(x)$ since $f$ is convex.

Note that all components of ${1 \over n}(x+\Pi x+\cdots+ \Pi^{n-1} x)$ are the same.

Hence we need only consider the function $\phi(\lambda) = f(\lambda e)$, where $e=(1,1,...,1)^T$ and the problem reduces to solving
$\min \{ \frac{M}{1 + \text{exp}(1 + \frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda})} | \lambda \ge 0, M \lambda \le R\}$. The cost function is strictly decreasing (look at the derivative), hence a minimizer is at $\lambda = {R \over M}$, hence
$x={R \over M} e$ solves the original problem.

Comment: Thanks. However, I am sorry that I forget to show the original problem without assumption $C_i = 1$ for $i = 1,2,...,M$. I just fix it. Do you have any good suggestion now?

Comment: You could try to use a projected gradient approach. Compute the cost gradient and project onto the simplex. You will need some step size rule with this approach.